# What code is "int pos" within vb.net?

Tags: vb.net, console, int

What code is "int pos" within vb.net?

Need someone to translate.

Appreciated,

Comment: http://www.developerfusion.com/tools/convert/csharp-to-vb/

Answer (score 2):

C#

```
int pos;
```

equals to:

VB.NET

```
Dim pos as Integer
```

Answer (score 0):

It is simple in VB.NET:

```
dim pos as integer
```

In C# it is:

```
int pos;
```

Answer (score 0):

yes correct VB or vb.net declare a variable like this way, Dim a as integer. so the same way u need to do Dim pos as integer.

Answer (score 0):

The C# `int` keyword denotes a signed 32-bit integer, resolving to the `System.Int32` structure.

The VB.NET counterpart to the C# 32-bit signed integer is `Integer` and you can declare one, like this:

```
Dim pos As Integer
```

> Note: It is also possible to use the .NET Framework strucure of `System.Int32`, but it is rarely done as there are language keywords that resolve to these structures and are generally more appealing than the `System` counterparts.

C#:

```
System.Int32 pos;
```

VB.NET:

```
Dim pos As System.Int32
```

---

For the integer types, here is the breakdown of how C# and VB.NET supports each of them:

16-bit integer

- `short` (C#)
- `Short` (VB.NET)
- `System.Int16` (.NET Framework)

32-bit integer

- `int` (C#)
- `Integer` (VB.NET)
- `System.Int32` (.NET Framework)

64-bit integer

- `long` (C#)
- `Long` (VB.NET)
- `System.Int64` (.NET Framework)